# document.write not printing

Tags: javascript, html

When I enter the inputs, it only outputs the value of Celsius but not Fahrenheit. I want my input to have 1 decimal place. Why is that and how do I fix it?

```
<script>
            
            let fahrenheit = prompt("Input a Fahrenheit temperature:");
            
            let celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
            
        </script>
        <p>
            <script>document.write("Fahrenheit: " + fahrenheit.toFixed(1));</script>   
        </p>
        <p>
            <script>
                document.write("Celsius: " + celsius.toFixed(1));
            </script>  
        </p>
```

Comment: Slightly tangential, but `document.write()` has been considered obsolete for quite some time now. You really should be writing data to DOM elements directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toFixed() is a method of Number.  You first need to convert your string to a float

```html
<script>
            
            let fahrenheit = prompt("Input a Fahrenheit temperature:");
            
            let celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
            
        </script>
        <p>
            <script>document.write("Fahrenheit: " + parseFloat(fahrenheit).toFixed(1));</script>   
        </p>
        <p>
            <script>
                document.write("Celsius: " + parseFloat(celsius).toFixed(1));
            </script>  
        </p>
```